# Send data from Angular 5 to PHP

Tags: php, angular5

I am trying to send data from angular to PHP. I am using Angular 5.

Here is my Angular service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SendDataService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }
configUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/myQuiz/testing/';

sendData(data:any) {
           return this.http.post(this.configUrl, data).map(res=>res.json());
}
}
```

in view.component.ts

```
   const data = {url: url};
    this.sendData.sendData(data).subscribe((status) => {
        this.postStatus = status;
    });
```

and in index.php

```
$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$req = json_decode($postdata);
print_r($postdata);
```

print_r returns me nothing. Whereas in the section Network of console I see this result

[image]

help please

Comment: try $_POST instead  file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: I have tried it. Again it returns me nothing

Comment: @GoharHovhannisyan did you manage to solve this?